# Using controls as basis for quantile/tertile categorization

Tags: distributions, continuous-data, case-control-study

I have a number of continuous but really skewed variables in the statistical analyses I am currently performing. Even though I am strongly in favour of keeping them just as they are and relaxing linearity assumptions by using splines, several faculty suggestions favour categorization for various reasons, including ease of interpretation, tradition, comparison with former studies in the field and [some other unsupported claims](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20079/the-effect-of-skewed-continuous-predictors-in-a-binary-logistic-regression-model).

The most recent suggestion has been to categorize the variables in the case population based on the tertile/quantile distribution among the control population. The argument is that the control population is the "normal" standard against which the case population should be viewed. It appears to be fairly common in epidemiological studies. However, no one ever justifies the logic. See for example, strategy outlined [in this SAS instructional site](http://www.pauldickman.com/teaching/sas/quintiles.php).

a) Isn't the approach of categorizing variables in the case population using the distribution of the variables in the control population the same as using the outcome (case/control status) to determine categories and hence, strongly biases effect estimates?

b) If I must categorize, is it better to categorize on the basis of the whole population (cases and controls) taken together or base the categorization on distribution in the controls alone?

Any thoughts, references, insights on the pros and cons of this suggested control-based categorization method would be really appreciated!